# ADB Connection problem

Tags: android, adb

This question is on Android ADB. I am fairly new on Android / ADB.

My requirement is to have a synchronous / "continuous data transfer" kind of connection using ADB (with the device and hosted PC).

Currently i need to invoke the ADB shell each and every time when i want to send some data/file to the device, Is it possible to have a "continuous-data-transfer" kind of connection. 
I looked into port-forwarding and similar stuffs and got the understanding that you can actually configure two ports on device + PC to have a connection, but not sure if we need to invoke ADB shell each time.

Please let me know if you need any further info on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a shell script? In linux kernels, you can use `wc` on the output of adb devices, to find the number of devices, and then if the device exist you connect to it and in the script you can do whatever you want to.

does this solve the issue??

I am not exactly 100% sure it would work, but i am just saying that its a possible option.